# Absolute maxvalue comparison of columns in Firebird SQL

Tags: sql, firebird

I want to perform comparison for the specified columns in database, the comparison logic should compare the numbers regardless of their signs and will retrieve the result original with its sign.

For example, below code works well but as can be seen in the select block it returns the absolute value of columns. Is there any trick, cheat in Firebird 2.1 to overcome that?

```
SELECT a.ELM_NUM,a.COMBO, maxvalue(abs(a.N_1),abs(a.N_2)) as maxN from ntm a order by a.ELM_NUM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`CASE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-conditional-case) condition:

```
SELECT a.ELM_NUM,a.COMBO, 
    CASE WHEN abs(a.N_1) > abs(a.N_2) THEN a.N_1 ELSE a.N_2 END as maxN 
from ntm a 
order by a.ELM_NUM
```